How to ensure map displays correctly within Avada's tabs?
I am using the Avada website builder to create a tab layout displaying the different police districts of Milwaukee.
The maps display perfectly on their own, but when put into a tabs the first tab displays correctly, but the rest look like this:
Example of funky map
I read that leaflet struggles sometimes with maps that are hidden and then shown and I have seen some solutions (such as adding js to redraw the map after being initialized). I unfortunately don't know how to apply that to Avada, and/or I am doing something wrong.
HERE IS THE CODE(this is the template I work off of--I replace IDS & such for individual districts.)
If it's relevant, the ID tabs follow this convention: #fusion-tab-district1, #fusion-tab-district2, and so on (to 7).
I looked at this:
Leaflet map not displayed properly inside tabbed panel
I can't tell if I'm misunderstanding or it's conflicting with Avada.
Let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example
